# Cannot manage received data through API

Tags: angular, get, httprequest, destructuring

I'm working on a portfolio project (am still a beginner) and I'm stuck almost at the start. I cannot handle the data I receive (though I have to say that I never saw such a JSON format until now).

Here is the code I try to convert to my needs:

```
Code sample

{
 "data": {
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "slug": "bitcoin",
    "circulating_supply": 17199862,
    etc...       
      }
   },
 "status": {
    "timestamp": "2022-08-11T16:54:56.636Z",
    "error_code": 0,
    etc...
  }
}
```

As you see I received an object and within that object, two nested object and so on. Sadly I worked with arrays until now so I struggle here a lot.
I use the http get request to get the data:

```
fetchAllCryptos() {
   const idParams = new HttpParams().set('string');
   return this.http.get(
   'API URL',
   {
    headers: {
      ...
    },
    params: idParams,
  }
)
.pipe(
  map((items) => {
    const { data: dataObject, status: statusObject } = items;
    console.log(dataObject, statusObject);
  })
);
```

}

I tried to destructure the received object but I receive an error that "Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'." How come? I hard-coded the same received object into my project and destructured the object there and it WORKED:

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   const { data, status } = this.object;
 }  
 object = {
  data: {
    '1': {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Bitcoin',
      symbol: 'BTC',
      etc
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map` function doesn't return anything.

```
.pipe(
  map((items) => {
    const { data: dataObject, status: statusObject } = items;
    console.log(dataObject, statusObject);
    // TODO: return something
  })
);
```

Or `tap` instead `map`

Comment: Both you and the person who also commented here were right. I didn't add a type which appears to mandatory in order for the data to be handled properly. Moreover, I didn't return anything indeed.
Both got corrected and now everything works just fine. Thank you!